# Why does the java accepts integer with a '+' sign and how to not accept integer input with a '+' sign

Tags: java

Why does the java accepts integer with a '+' sign and how to not accept integer input with a '+' sign. Please help! Thanks in advance

```
nAmount= scan.nextInt();
String sAmount = Integer.toString(nAmount);
//ON THIS LINE, MY PROG SHOULD NOT ACCEPT INTEGERS WITH "+" SIGN
if (sAmount.contains("+")) {
  System.out.println("金額に文字が入力されています。");
} else if (nAmount<=0) {
  System.out.println("金額は0円以上で入力してください。");
} else if (nAmount>999999) {
  System.out.println("金額は999,999円以下で入力してください。");
} else nAFlag =1;

Sample Output :
Input > 100 (Accepted)
Input > -100 (Not Accepted because of the constrain input is less than 0)
Input > +100 (IT SHOULD NOT BE ACCEPTED BECAUSE IT CONTAINS A SYMBOL)
```

Comment: what exactly are you asking? could you give examples of what you mean?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I need to write a code that accepts only numbers, without any characters or symbols. But when I input integer with "+" sign the program accept it.

Comment: Assuming you're referring to something like `Integer.parseInt()` or `Scanner.nextInt()`, it accepts a `+` sign [because that's how it's specified to work](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Comment: @kristintirin please show your code. It is very unclear what you mean.

Comment: Because integer read it as a positive integer. so how can I validate it. I need only numbers no any symbols

Comment: @kristintirin **please show your code**. "Java" doesn't "accept integers", specific methods in the Java API do; we need to see which methods you are using in order to advise you. [Edit] your question so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: The expression `sAmount.contains("+")` will never be `true` as `Integer.toString(nAmount)` does not add a sign prefix to positive integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading an int using [`Scanner.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int)): as described in the documentation, this uses [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) to read the number; and that method explicitly states that it accepts a leading `+` sign:

> The characters in the string must all be digits of the specified radix (as determined by whether Character.digit(char, int) returns a nonnegative value), except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value **or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value**

And once you've read that number, there's no way to distinguish the fact that you entered `123` or `+123`, because there's no difference in the value. So, you've lost the `+` even before you convert the `int` to a `String`.

To capture this, you need to read the `String` first, and convert *that* to an `int`:

```
String sAmount= scan.next();
nAmount = Integer.parseInt(sAmount);
```

This preserves the `+` sign in `sAmount`, because there is no reason to strip it away. Note that it will fail if `sAmount` can't actually be parsed as an `int`.